# I am facing NoSuchMethod error in Flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

[this error comes when i run app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZPeb.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZPeb.png)

```
children: [
        Question(
          question[_questionindex]['questionText'],
        ),
        ...(question[_questionindex]['answers'] as List<String>)
            .map((answer) {
          return Answer(_answer, answer);
        }).toList()
      ],
```

note (the answer is class name)
**it is not showing error in editor but when I run this I get this error in emulator 
I am beginner in *Flutter* and *dart* still learning
please help me resolving this issue I am facing it from 2 days and can't find it on google also**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - The method 'map' was called on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51036758/flutter-the-method-map-was-called-on-null)

Comment: yes brother i saw this before but didn't helped me

Comment: @DailyBatain : `(question[_questionindex]['answers'] as List<String>)`  probably returns null that's why you are getting that error. As mentioned in the linked answer either use `(question[_questionindex]['answers'] as List<String>)?.map` or handle null other ways.

Comment: didn't helped bro @MidhunMP